# Understanding python try catch else finally clause behavior

Tags: python

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:07:21)

I have this:

```
def f():
    try:
        print "a"
        return
    except:
        print "b"
    else:
        print "c"
    finally:
        print "d"
f()
```

This gives:

```
a
d
```

and not the expected

```
a 
c 
d
```

If I comment out the return, then I will get

```
a 
c 
d
```

How do I remember this behavior in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, consult [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try):

> The optional `else` clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the `try` clause
>
> Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an exception or the execution of a `return`, `continue`, or `break` statement.

Since you're `return`ing from the body of the `try` block, the `else` will not be executed.

Comment: I like to make the analogy of a man walking down the statements one by one. "Flows off the end" to me is like saying "keeps walking past the `try`".

Answer (score 2):

`finally` blocks *always* happen, save for catastrophic failure of the VM.  This is part of the contract of `finally`.

You can remember this by remembering that this is what `finally` does.  Don't be confused by other control structures like if/elif/else/while/for/ternary/whatever statements, because they do not have this contract.  `finally` does.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` block hooked up to a try block is not special in terms of exception mechanics - it's similar to just putting code in the body of the function after the try block. The only function is being able execute "normal" code between a try block and a finally block. This does mean however that if the function returns before getting to the else block it will never execute.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Python documentation!

You would use this for exception handling, bookmark this page!

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You enter the `try` block.
2. You `print "a"`.
3. You encounter the `return` statement and the function returns.
4. Since `finally` blocks always execute, though, everything in the `finally` block happens before the function actually ends its execution.

The `else` block is only entered if the `try` block has been completed and no exception occurred. Because you `return`ed in the `try` block, it wasn't completed, even though no exception occurred nonetheless. It is as if you never had a `try`/`else` block at all, and you put all the code on the same level of indentation.

`try`/`else` exists more for the sake of code organization; unless a `finally` block is added, it is the same thing as using no `else` block at all. The following are functionally equivalent:

```
try:
    print "foo"
except:
    print "woops"
else:
    print "bar"

try:
    print "foo"
except:
    print "woops"
print "bar"
```

However, you must use `else` if you are going to use `finally`. This has no meaning:

```
try:
    print "foo"
except:
    print "woops"
print "bar"
finally:
    print "done"
```

What was the `finally` supposed to refer to in this case? Ergo you must use `else` if you are going to use `finally` unless you did not intend for anything to happen after the `try` block but before the `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

When a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement is executed in the `try` suite of a `try`…`finally` statement, the `finally` clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’ A `continue` statement is illegal in the `finally` clause. (The reason is a problem with the current implementation — this restriction may be lifted in the future).

This is actually from the documentation.